# Python writing to new lines

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get this code to ask for the user's details then save them to a .txt file with commas separating the strings. I need to write to a new line every time I run the code but adding "/n" onto the end of the strings but it gives me all the user's data on the same line. any help?

```
print ("enter your name, age, and year group and password")
while True:
    reg_name = input("Name:"))
    reg_pass = input ("Password:")
    reg_age = input ("age:")
    reg_group = input ("Year Group")
    print ("Is this infomation correct?")
    print ("Name:",reg_name)
    print ("password:",reg_pass)
    print ("Age:",reg_age)
    print ("Year Group:", reg_group)
    reg_correct = input ("[Y/N]").lower()
    if reg_correct == "y":
        reg_user = reg_name[0:3]+reg_age
        reg_write = open("D:\\Computer science\\Computing test\\logindata.txt","a")
        reg_write.write (reg_user+","+reg_name+","+reg_pass+","+reg_age+","+reg_group+"/n")
        print ("Your username is:",reg_user)
        reg_write.close()
        break
    elif reg_correct == "n":
        print ("Please Re-enter your infomation")
    else:
        Print ("Invalid input! Please try again...!")
```

Comment: `"/n"` is a slash followed by a 'n'.  `"\n"` is the actual newline character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may want `\n` instead of `/n`. It is the actual newline character. Otherwise, it would be adding "/n" between each statement in the file. `\n` creates a newline.

```
print ("enter your name, age, and year group and password")
while True:
    reg_name = input("Name:"))
    reg_pass = input ("Password:")
    reg_age = input ("age:")
    reg_group = input ("Year Group")
    print ("Is this infomation correct?")
    print ("Name:",reg_name)
    print ("password:",reg_pass)
    print ("Age:",reg_age)
    print ("Year Group:", reg_group)
    reg_correct = input ("[Y/N]").lower()
    if reg_correct == "y":
        reg_user = reg_name[0:3]+reg_age
        reg_write = open("D:\\Computer science\\Computing test\\logindata.txt","a")
        reg_write.write (reg_user+","+reg_name+","+reg_pass+","+reg_age+","+reg_group+"\n")
        print ("Your username is:",reg_user)                                       #   ^^^
        reg_write.close()
        break
    elif reg_correct == "n":
        print ("Please Re-enter your infomation")
    else:
        Print ("Invalid input! Please try again...!")
```

Comment: I feel stupid now, something so simple can mess my whole program up, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Different way :**

You can also avoid escape character by using **writelines()**  method .

```
reg_write.writelines (reg_user+","+reg_name+","+reg_pass+","+reg_age+","+reg_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `print` function to write your information to a file. By using the `pathlib` module, you can easily run some error checking to help verify your file is accessible. With Python's recent addition of format strings, printing out variables can be very easy to accomplish.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib


def main():
    while True:
        username = input('Username: ')
        password = input('Password: ')
        year_age = input('Age:      ')
        grouping = input('Group:    ')
        print('Is this information correct?')
        print(f'Username: {username}\n'
              f'Password: {password}\n'
              f'Age:      {year_age}\n'
              f'Group:    {grouping}')
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        answer = input('Yes or no? ').casefold()
        if 'yes'.startswith(answer):
            path = pathlib.Path('login_data.csv')
            if path.exists() and not path.is_file():
                print('Your information cannot be saved.')
            else:
                with path.open('at') as file:
                    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
                    print(
                        username, password, year_age, grouping,
                        sep=',', file=file
                    )
            break
        elif 'no'.startswith(answer):
            print('Please enter your information so that it is correct.')
        else:
            print('I did not understand your answer. Please try again.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```